# How to extract a part of the string between two characters in bash?

Tags: regex, string, bash

I am trying to extract a part of the string using bash. The string is in the format:

```
peeyush (>= 5) peeyush (<= 7)
```

Now I want to extract the numbers in the braces in two variables. Something like

```
echo $var1
>=5
echo $var2
<=7
```

Or even better if it is possible to extract the numbers in min and max format from the string?

Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this grep:

```
s='peeyush (>= 5) peeyush (<= 7)'

unset var1 var2
while read -r p; do
    [[ -z "$var1" ]] && var1="$p" || var2="$p"
done < <(grep -oP '\(\K[^)]+' <<< "$s")

echo "$var1"
>= 5
echo "$var2"
<= 7
```

Comment: I guess the OP also wants the `>=` part.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. Though I have a doubt, some of these numbers are not exactly in single digit format. Actually these are version numbers, some are like 1.4.7 or 1.16, how should I modify the regex to separate them?

Comment: This solution should work for `'peeyush (>= 2.1.5) peeyush (<= 1.4.7)'` also.

Comment: This solution is giving me error:test.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
test.sh: line 8: `done < <(grep -oP '\(\K[^)]+' <<< "$s")'

Comment: Make sure you use BASH when you execute it. Place `#!/bin/bash` on top of your script.

Comment: ok can you paste your script in question so I can investigate.

Comment: Yeah, looks like some issues with my system. Anyways, can you help me making changes in the regex "read var1 var2 <<< $(grep -oP '\d+(?=\*\))' <<< "$s")" to include the numbers with dots? Right now it only includes digits.

Comment: Don't use `read var1 var2 <<< $(grep -oP '\d+(?=*))' <<< "$s")` if string can contain spaces. Use it the way I showed above and in the link I provided.